# Как работает alignas()?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int distance(void* first, void* second)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<int>(first) - reinterpret_cast<int>(second);
}

int main()
{
     alignas(16) int f[4];
     alignas(1024) int s[4];
     std::cout << distance(f, s);

     return 0;
}
```

Никак не могу понять как работает `alignas()`. Почему расстояние равно 2016, а без него 24?

Comment: У меня этот код вообще не компилируется http://cpp.sh/8igy2

Comment: В Visual Studio 2015 работает.

Comment: Очень странные цифры.  Можно предположить что собирается отладочная версия, и "лишнии" байты на стеке заняты сторожевыми значениями, для проверки выхода за пределы массивов.

Comment: У Вас в коде UB, поэтому цифры Вы можете видеть какие угодно. Нельзя вычитать из одного указателя другой, если они не указывают на один и тот же массив(либо же сразу за массив)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) - это новая штука с с++11 стандарта и предназначена, чтобы устаканить то, что творится в разных компиляторах. Чтобы не говорили разработчики других языков, но иногда нужно писать немножко низкоуровневого кода, чтобы получить существенный плюс в скорости.

Как известно, процессоры лучше работают с данными в памяти, если они выровнены по границе в 4/8/16 байт. А в некоторых случаях данные обязаны быть выровнены (например, с некоторыми SSE командами и на некоторых ARM процессорах).

Что такое выравнивание по границе? Это просто адрес, который кратен заданной степени двойки. То есть, адрес 24 выровнен по границе 2, 4, 8, но не 16. Адрес 1024 выровнен по 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 и многим другим. Можно сказать и по-другому - адрес, выровненный по границе 16 в бинарном виде заканчивается на 4 нуля.

`alignas` как раз и заставляет компилятор сделать это выравнивание. Да, часто это идет в ущерб памяти (появляются пустоты), но в некоторых случаях (с SSE) можно получить двукратный прирост просто по той причине, что адрес выровнен по границе 16/32. Почему так происходит? Все просто - современные процессоры уже давно не загружают данные по байту из памяти - они обычно грузят как минимум по 4 байта сразу, более того, грузят по выровненным адресам по границе 4. И если нужно загрузить 4 невыровненных байта, то процессору приходится делать это в три этапа - загружаем первые байт (но при этом загружаем 4 байта), потом загружаем вторую половину, а потом складываем в памяти. А так как операция обращения к памяти - медленная - это длится достаточно долго.

Нужно ли в своем коде постоянно писать выравнивание? Нет, не нужно. Компиляторы достаточно умные и сами могут догадаться. Но есть случаи, когда это лучше сделать.

- переменная используется для SSE/MMX.
- переменная-массив, достаточно большого размера, по которому нужно будет много итерироваться (бегать).
- числодробилки.

> Почему расстояние равно 2016, а без него 24?

а на ideone вообще получилось -252:)

`alignas` говорит "выровняй", а как именно разместить в памяти - это другое дело. В Вашем случае компилятор вначале разместил первую переменную по адресу кратному 16. Вторую, нужно разместить по адресу кратному 1024. Логично, что такое может быть как сразу (потому что первая переменная занимает ровно 16 байт, так и через много-много байт (мы же не знаем адреса первой переменной).

Многие компиляторы в отладочном режиме за массивами всегда добавляют несколько байт - для того, что бы препятствовать классическому выходу за пределы массива на один элемент. Поэтому, чтобы понять, почему там именно 2016 - нужно смотреть в конкретную версию компилятора и параметры компиляции.