# Как работает aligned_storage() С++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Прочитал про `aligned_storage()` на [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage), но так и не смог понять. Объясните, пожалуйста, попроще.

Comment: imho на [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/aligned_storage/) описано понятней всего.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: «[Как работает alignas()?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/616184/208074)»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разберём [указанную вами статью](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) по абзацам.

> Provides the member typedef type, which is a `PODType`...

Класс-обёртка `std::aligned_storage` является примитивным типом, то есть данные хранятся в нём непрерывной кучей байт (как структура в Си), без C++-заморочек. Благодаря этому его можно спокойно копировать хоть через `memcpy`.

> ... suitable for use as uninitialized storage...

Так как обёртка является примитивным типом, то у неё нет ни конструктора, ни деструктора. Соответственно, у оборачиваемого типа конструктор тоже вызван не будет. Как результат, мы можнем оборачивать только примитивные типы (увы).

> ... for any object whose size is at most `Len` and whose alignment requirement is a divisor of `Align`.

Оборачиваемый тип должен 1) полностью помещаться в обёртку и 2) его допустимое выравнивание (кратность адреса в оперативной памяти) должно быть делителем `Align`.

Возьмём следующий пример. Пусть `Align = 16`. Его делители — 1, 2, 4, 8 и 16. Это означает, что мы можем поместить в этот контейнер:

- `char`/`uint8_t`/`int8_t` (выравнивание — 1 байт),
- `uint16_t`/`int16_t` (выравнивание — 2 байта),
- `uint32_t`/`int32_t` (выравнивание — 4 байта),
- `uint64_t`/`int64_t` (выравнивание — 8 байт),
- либо SSE вектор, представленный в виде `uint8_t[16]` (ожидаемое выравнивание — 16 байт).

Зачем было введено выравнивание? Процессор обменивается с ОЗУ не байтами, а блоками фиксированного размера *2<sup>n</sup>* при неком целом *n*. Если переменная выровнена, то она может быть передана за наименее возможное количество пересылок. Невыровненные же данные могут пересечь границу блока и потребовать на одну пересылку больше.

В придачу, некоторые операции (команды быстрой выровненной загрузки в SSE, например), вообще выбрасывают прерывание процессора при отсутствии выравнивания на определённую границу (для SSE — 16 байт).

Стоит отметить, что *выравнивание равно размеру* **только** для примитивных типов. У составных же типов (структур и объединений) выравнивание равно таковому у наибольшего поля. Это гарантирует, что наиболее длинное поле будет выровнено по своему размеру. Ну а так как размеры примитивных типов равны степени двойки (то есть выравнивание больших типов кратно выравниванию типов меньших), то и все остальные поля будут выровнены.

> The default value of `Align` is the most stringent (the largest) alignment requirement for any object whose size is at most `Len`.

`Align` можно и не указывать. Тогда компилятор будет выравнивать так, как он бы выравнивал близжайший (но не превышающий) по размерам тип. То есть будто мы написали `std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>`, где `T` — некий встроенный (пусть и не существующий) тип с нужным нам размером.

> If the default value is not used, `Align` must be the value of `alignof(T)` for some type `T`, or the behavior is undefined.

Третий фрагмент текста перечислял типы, *допустимые* для размещения в конкретной специализации обёртки с конкретным размером и выравниванием. *Этот же* абзац налагает ограничение на *конкретный выбранный тип*: `Align` должен иметь типичное для данного типа выравнивание. То есть мы не можем разместить `uint16_t` с `Align=6`, полагая, что 6 и 3 — допустимые значения выравнивания, — это провоцирует неопределённое поведение (выше уже был приведён пример про выравнивание для SSE).

***Но данный фрагмент также запрещает задание `Align`, кратного настоящему выравниванию. К примеру, мы не можем разместить `uint16_t` с выравниванием в 4, 8, 12 и т. д. байт.***

***И да, мы не можем выравнивать SSE-вектор, если у нас нет готового, 16-байтного типа. Ведь тогда мы вынуждены использовать `char[16]`, чьё родное выравнивание — 1 байт (т. к. тип `char`). Нам же нужно 16 — здравствуй, неопределённое поведение? А будь у нас готовый тип — компилятор сам его выровняет по собственному размеру (который совпадает с требуемым выравниванием), и `std::aligned_storage` нам как бы и не нужен.***

> The behavior is undefined if `Len == 0`.

Обёртка должна иметь ненулевую длину (иначе в неё ничего не поместится).

Comment: Подождите, вроде ж наоборот? У нас alignment requirement = 16, и оно не делитель 2. Наоборот, 2 — делитель 16.

Comment: @VladD, перечитал — дошло. Это не правило вычисления выравнивания (как я думал в начале), это *ограничение* на допустимые оборачиваемые типы. Мы можем оборачивать любой тип, чьё выравнивание кратно делителю `Len`.

Comment: @VladD, хотя нет, не «кратно», а «строго равно». Хотелось бы узнать подробности касательно этого момента. Откуда такое ограничение на кратность? Ведь даже выравнивание 4-байтового `uint32_t` на границу в 8 байт должно быть допустимым.